# Focus EditText Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Como faço para obter o foco num `EditText` mas continuo com problemas?

Estou fazendo um sistema de pedidos, tenho 3 `EditText` (produto, quantidade e desconto) e um botão **Adicionar**.

Eu preciso que quando o usuário clique no botão adicionar, o foco volte para o campo produto, hoje o foco esta indo para um `editText` do `listView` (itens do pedido) que acabou de ser adicionado.

Então se o usuário adiciona 30 produtos ele tem que ficar rolando a tela pra cima e colocar o foco no produto.

Estou usando Android 4.1

Código (no `onclick` do botão adicionar)

```
try{
    validaProdutoLista(item, pedido.getListaItemPedido());

    pedido.adicionaItens(item);

    listViewItensPedidos.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, pedido.getListaItemPedido().size() * 50));

    TabelaItensPedidoAdapter adapter = new TabelaItensPedidoAdapter(PedidoActivity.this, pedido.getListaItemPedido());
    listViewItensPedidos.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.i(TAG, "Itens add "+pedido.getListaItemPedido().size());

    codProduto.setText("");
    codProduto.requestFocus(); //voltar o foco para o produto
}catch (MyException e){
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: tenta usar o request focus no xml

Comment: Se eu usar o requestFocus no xml, o foco ja vai para o campo logo que abre a tela, mas não é isso que eu preciso, preciso que só quando for adicionado um produto que o foco volte para o EditText produto.

Comment: Assim como estas a fazer deveria funcionar...

Comment: @JorgeB. isso que é o ruim do Android, o que deveria funcionar as vezes não funciona dependendo da versão e do dispositivo... Talvez tenha que ver outra solução

Comment: Alves tenta fazer `codProduto.clearFocus();` antes do `codProduto.requestFocus();`

Comment: então Jorge, não mudou nada, o foco sempre vai para o editText do listView que foi adicionado.

Comment: Se alguém tiver alguma outra ideia, será muito bem vinda..rs

Comment: Qual é o nome do *editText* da *listView* que está a receber o *focus*?

Comment: @AlvesFelipe Na linha com `codProduto.requestFocus();` mude para  `codProduto.requestFocus(FOCUS_UP, null);` e veja o que acontece. e tambem crie uma var do tipo boolean para ver se o codProduto.requestFocus esta retornando true ou false.

Comment: ramaral, o nome é itbProduto.

Comment: Olimon, não adiantou, o foco continua indo para o próximo campo, mas retorna true no codProduto.requestFocus

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que não esteja funcionando porque você está setando o foco no momento em que você ainda está apertando o botão (você está mudando o foco dentro do on click).

Uma possível solução é usar um Handler. Você adiciona um atributo do tipo Handler na sua classe e no onclick você manda uma mensagem para o Handler.

Veja esse exemplo:

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
...
final Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.i("HANDLER", "handleMessage::recebendo msg " + msg.what);
        codProduto.setText("");
        codProduto.requestFocus(); //voltar o foco para o produto
    }
};
```

Aí no onClick você faz, no lugar onde está a requisição do foco você manda uma mensagem para o Handler:

```
myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Comment: Seria interessante incluir a alternativa sem `Handler` usando  apenas `postRunnable` no próprio `EditText`.

Comment: Derzu, realmente é isso que acontece, eu criei um Handler e funcionou certinho.

Comment: Wakim, fiz como você sugeriu e também funcionou. Muito obrigado a todos pela ajuda!!